# Show UIButton Done on UIScrollView for Images only when user taps on image view

Tags: iphone, ios6, uigesturerecognizer

How can i code for UIButton to show only when user taps on UIScrollView for images.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad

{    
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
   imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 10, 60, 35);

    [myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [myButton.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

    myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;

    myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

    [myButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageScrollView addSubview:myButton];
    [imageView release];
}
imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:imageScrollView];
[imageScrollView release];
}
```

Right now it is displaying on every image view but i want it should Show UIButton Done only when taps on the screen.

EDIT: If i add

```
 [imageView addGestureRecognizer: tap];
```

and initiate Gesturerecognizer

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
   tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
  [tap release];
```

then how can i code in handle tap method to show done button when user taps on image view

```
 - (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)tap {

   }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the gesture recognizer on the image view and not on the ViewController.

Also, you need to enable the user interaction for the image view like this:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `UIScrollViewDelegate` Method when you will scroll show your button will be shown and then if you want to hide that button hide it.

And for handleTap you set `[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];` instead of `[self addGestureRecognizer:tap];`

create your button in `ViewDidLoad` and hide it initially and when user will tap image just set`

```
button.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];- (void)handleTap:(id)sender{
             _myButton.hidden = NO;
             
         }
not working when tapping

Comment: set delegate like tap.delegate = self; and go to .h file and write <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

Comment: can u tell me what problem are you facing ? put one break poing in your handleTap then check is it going to that method or not.

Comment: i added breakpoint at the handle tap and it is going to that method. wondering why then it is not showing done button

Comment: set button.hidden = NO; and set background color to check button frame.

Comment: and first add it in view did load with same frame and then add it in your method then play with hide and show.

Comment: BOOL numberofTaps; - (void)handleTap:(id)sender{
    //_myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 10, 60, 35);
    
    if   (numberofTaps == 1){
        
        

        _myButton.hidden = NO;}
    
         } still no success

Comment: when i add breakpoint to handletap method why in result it shows buttonFlags(<anonymous struct>)all propertiesof button are unsigned int:1 why is that

Comment: i forgot to add the property of gesture recognizer added that too now @property (nonatomic, assign) UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer; but still no success

Comment: Write one NSLog and then check is it printing that log or not ? If it is printing the log that means there is some problem with your code to show button.